# Passing array to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

Though we declare a function with an integer array, we pass address of the array to the function. In the case of simple integers it gives error if we pass address we get pointer conversion error. But how its possible in case of an array

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_array(int array[][100],int x, int y);
main()
{
    int i,j,arr[100][100];
    printf("Enter the array");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    print_array(arr,i,j);

}

void print_array(int array[][100],int x,int y)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\nThe values are\n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is even though our function is declared as one with integer array as first parameter (here) we are passing array address when we call the function. How does it function?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?  Here is a code sample without errors: https://www.ideone.com/CAEoi.  In fact I can run the code you have written and it gives what I expect as well https://www.ideone.com/3z1JO

Comment: from your code snippet, you will end up passing in x and y as 2 since you are using those in your for loop where you are reading values. You also you are only initializing a[0][0],a[0][1],a[1][0],a[1][1] with data, the rest of the array is just going to be junk (on the upside you are only printing out what you initialized).

Comment: @pstrjds My question is not about getting error. Its about the logic behind its working. Question now updated. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: hm....!You function gets as first parameter int[][] which translates as int**.When you call your function you call it as print_array(arr,i,j); arr is also int **;Why you declared it as int [][100] ?

Comment: @nikosdi when i declared it as int [][] it gave the following error `array type has incomplete element type`

Comment: @nikosdi: It actually translates as `int*`, although your mistake is very very common.  In a multidimensional array, there are no arrays of pointers.  Which is why all trailing dimensions must be known to locate the various elements in memory.

Comment: You might want to read section 6 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/). Since you're already there, read the other sections too :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your are passing the array, not its address.
`arr` is an int[][] array
(in fact it is pretty the same as `&(arr[0])`, which is a pointer to (the address of) the first line of your array. In C, there is no practical difference between an array and the corresponding pointer, except you take it's address with the & operator.)

Edit: Ok, just to make me clear:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fn(char p1 [][100], char (*p2)[100])
{
  if (sizeof(p1)!=sizeof(p2))
    printf("I'm failed. %i <> %i\n",sizeof(p1),sizeof(p2));
  else
    printf("Feeling lucky. %i == %i\n",sizeof(p1),sizeof(p2));
}

int main()
{
  char arr[5][100];
  char (*p)[100]=&(arr[0]);
  fn(arr, arr);
  fn(p, p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int[][]` isn't a valid type.  `int[][100]` is, which is what he's using.  And the array decays into `&(arr[0][0])` (your note about the address of the first element is correct, you were simply missing an index).

Comment: Yes, I meant int[][n], but as n was irrelevant here, I omitted, as would not affect the explanation. And the index was not missing. arr _is_ equal to &(arr[0]).

Comment: *n* is not irrelevant, it's absolutely necessary for offset calculation.  Also, `&(arr[0])` is invalid, since you can't take the address of an rvalue.  Finally, you're wrong when you say there's no practical difference.  Although arrays decay automatically to pointers where necessary, they are quite different.  For example, `sizeof(arr)` is not the size of a pointer.

Comment: n is irrelevant from the point of my answer. could be 1, 100 or 42. by "int[][]" I meant "a two dimensional integer array", didnt focused on its size. Next time I will be more specific :). &(arr[0]) IS VALID. if arr is an int[][]. Ooops, sorry if arr is an int[][100]; Just try it.

Comment: But `&(arr[0])` is probably not the type you expected it to be: http://ideone.com/O1Ecw.

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at.  The function parameter actually is a pointer, despite being declared as an array.  But that doesn't mean that arrays and pointers are the same, with local variables they definitely aren't.  In C you can never have a parameter of array type.  (In C++ you can have a reference parameter of array type, but it inherits C's prohibition on passing raw arrays by value directly in a parameter, although there are workarounds such as putting the array inside a structure, and using the structure for the parameter)