# A function calling Multidimensional array

Tags: c

How to pass a multidimensional array to any function like arr[n][m][p], how to pass this array to a function?

Comment: by writing its name in parentheses after the name of the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array to a function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278989/passing-array-to-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

with it's pointer.
decleration should be like that:
Function(type*** arr)

and when you call the function from your code:
Function(arr);

(the number of your asterisks [ * ] should be as the dimension of your array).

Answer (score 0):

Like a normal array.

Example, of getting the value from an 3D array:

```
int a=arr[*][*][*]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int <name of variable>=<array name><first cordinate><second cordinate><thrid cordinate>

 * = Whatever number you want
```

Hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array along with its dimensions (numbers of elements). Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

func(int m, int n, int p, int a[n][m][p])
{
    int j, k, l;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++, printf("\n"))
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++, printf("\t"))
    for (l = 0; l < p; l++)
        printf("%3d", a[k][j][l]);    // print to check
}

main()
{
    int m = 2, n = 3, p = 4, arr[n][m][p], i = 0, j, k, l;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    for (l = 0; l < p; l++)
        arr[k][j][l] = i++; // initialize the array somehow
    func(m, n, p, arr);     // pass array along with dimensions
}
```